# How to make Capybara find an element that appears and disappears quickly (loading spinner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have an application for which you can select a checkbox, click a submit button and then have a value update. In the real world the click triggers an API call and values are updated with the response. Between the time the API is called and a value returned, I also set the value-to-be-updated-area to be populated with a spinner (a loading spinner). This works great in real life usage. But, in test, I want to make sure that spinner shows up, disappears and then the new value is in place. In the test environment (using `rspec`) I have setup a `sinatra` fake service to respond to all API calls via `webmock`'s `stub_request`.

So the problem is that sinatra is really quickly giving the value, so quick that capybara never sees the spinner. (I think that's the problem)

I tried artificially slowing down the sinatra response for these kinds of feature specs, but it didn't work. And besides I'd rather not because I want the suite to be fast. Here's a sample spec:

```rb
    it 'lets the user change the pickup library of a hold', js: true do
      visit holds_path
      page.check 'hold_list__3911148'
      page.select 'A terrific value', from: 'some_dropdown'
      page.click_button 'Update Selected Things'
      expect(page).to have_css 'spinner-border' # this will _always_ fail to be detected
      expect(page).to have_css '#hold3911148 .pickup_at', text: 'York'
    end
```

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: I've tried `:selenium`, `:selenium_headless`, `:selenium_chrome` and `:selenium_chrome_headless`. I go with `:selenium_chrome_headless` as my default for feature specs with js.

Comment: Are you sure the element actually appears? What does "it didn't work" mean in the context of slowing your Sinatra response? If Sinatra never responds then the spinner should be there indefinitely and visible, what happens then? "I want the suite to be fast" is nice but if it is not representative of your app in the real world then it's not a useful constraint.

Comment: Yes, the element appears, that's what I meant by "works great in real life usage" - it also shows the spinner in test if I add `sleep` to my faked web service in sinatra when I use a "headed" browser. "It didn't work" means it didn't find the spinner, the spec failed. If I try to extend the sleep so that it in affect never responds, and even though I can see a browser perform the operation and see the spinner appear, the spec fails saying it can't find that spinner. I am willing to sacrifice speed of the suite for accuracy of the tests, I was curious if there was something I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Tests and the app run asynchronously so if you really need to validate the spinner appears then your only option is to slow down the response for that test enough to let the spinner actually appear and be seen. Depending on which driver you're using and how the browser driver (chromedriver, geckodriver, etc) author have chosen to implement button clicks the amount of time you have to wait may be longer than you expect. This is because driver authors may opt to have button clicks wait for a bit to see if they trigger page loads, and Capybara can't start looking for the spinner until `click_button` returns.

I know you said that slowing down the response "didn't work" but without any details on exactly what you did there it's tough to diagnose that. This also assumes that all the browser calls are going to your app and your app is then making calls to the external service (which you're faking via your sinatra app) before returning (webmock can't be used to fake external API calls made directly from the browser)

Comment: Yeah it's the application making the API call, not the browser. Basically I just added a `sleep` of `5` on the API call being faked. There is a lot of context here I realize, but if this helps, I added that sleep as line 31 at https://github.com/psu-libraries/myaccount/blob/master/spec/support/fake_symphony.rb#L31. And thank you for writing/maintaining `capybara`.

Comment: @cdmo Assuming that is actually being hit, I would expect it allow for showing of the spinner.  To test it do something extreme like `sleep 30` there and see if you can see the spinner in the browser when the test is running.

Comment: so I tried 30 and I tried on various drivers. On each run I got the same response of  `expected to find css "spinner-border" but there were no matches`. When I watch the test run on a headed browser what I observe is that the click operation happens, the spinner appears, then a few seconds later the whole browser screen goes blank white and then several seconds later the browser window closes. Thank you again for any help/suggestions. Maybe I'm coming at this wrong?

Comment: @cdmo Are you sure your css is right? If the spinner has an id of 'spinner-border' you want `have_css('#spinner-border')`

Comment: @cdmo Actually looking at your code you probably want `have_css('.spinner-border')` since 'spinner-border' is a class being used on a span or maybe div element (do `div.spinner-border` to be a bit faster/more efficient, etc if you want

Comment: Yep, it's a `class` not an `id`, thanks for taking a look. Still not able to get capybara to find that elusive spinner though, unfortunately. Is it faster to qualify the selector with the tag? I've always read that is slower. https://vanseodesign.com/css/css-selector-performance/

Comment: That article is from 2011...  but since your code shows multiple element types using the same class I’d check for the one you actually expect in this case